# Type mismatch, required node, found string

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx-html

Trying to use the snippet at `Kotlin` site under `HTML Builder` tap, so I wrote the below:

```
val tbl = createHTML().table {
    for ((num, string) in data) {
        tr {
            td { +"$num" }
            td { +string }
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById("container")!!.appendChild(tbl)
```

but the IDE is underlying the `tbl` with error as below:

[image]

What mistake I;m doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createHtml()` produces a String, which cannot be passed to `appendChild()`. You should instead use

```
val tbl = document.create.table {
    ...
}
```

which produces an HTMLElement (which is a Node) or simply skip the variable.

```
document.getElementById("container")!!.append.table {
    ...
}
```

`createHTML().xxx` is best used with server `Ktor.io` where you create something like:

```
val html = createHTML().html {
                        body {
                        form(action = "/login", encType = FormEncType.applicationXWwwFormUrlEncoded, method = FormMethod.post) {
                            p {
                                +"user:"
                                textInput(name = "user") {
                                    value = principal?.name ?: ""
                                }
                            }

                            p {
                                +"password:"
                                passwordInput(name = "pass")
                            }

                            p {
                                submitInput() { value = "Login" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Then send it to the browser using:

```
call.respondText(html, ContentType.Text.Html)
```